# Angular js : send Carriage Return

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

I am automating a Angular web application using Karma framework. I have encountered a situation where i need to handle the pop-up message . In order to handle it, i need to click on the "OK" or "cancel" button [OR] just simply hit the "Enter" key. I was searching how to send a "carriage return" in Karma API using angular js , but could not find a solution i needed.  below is my sample code. Any suggestions ?

```
it('should delete a setting', function()  {

     browser().navigateTo('#/launchparms');
     element('#editParameter').click();
     browser().navigateTo('#/launchparms/edit/{{ launchParm.id }}');
     input('name').enter('parameter');
     input('value').enter('value');
     element('#launchParmsDeleteBtn').click();
     // this is where i need to send a 'carriage return'.
     browser().navigateTo('#/launchparms');
     expect(element('#launchParmsLink').text()).toEqual(' Launch Parameters');

});
```

Comment: This task isn't really suited for Karma (which is meant for automated unit tests--not integration tests). Perhaps you should look at Protractor (which is the tool for integration tests)?

Comment: Oh ok . But i have used this for e2e mainly. this is just one case which i could not handle.

Comment: Right, you can fit a round peg into a square hole, but it's easier if you just use a square peg in the first place, no?